# jQuery/javascript uppercase all text regardless of id

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi all I'm working on local server with XAMPP my problem is I need something to transform all input tags with type of text to uppercase while typing without knowing the id of the element, but I can't figure the way to do this as there is no getElementsByType.

What i want is something like this

HTML Code

```
<input type="text" id="var1">
<input type="text" id="var2">
```

JS Code

```
var x=document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++){
    var node = x[i];
    if(node.getAttribute("type") == 'text'){
        //From my research I learnt this is how I select all text areas so I think
        //this is where uppercase transformer is going to be written but don't know how
    }
}
```

PS: I'm new to jQuery and javaScript

By the way I'm not working only in english characters so my problem consists characters like ş ç ö ê etc.

Comment: `== text` is testing against a variable NAMED `text`, which doesn't exist in your code. You need `== 'text'`, which tests against a STRING whose contents is `text`.

Comment: @MarcB oh you are right, edited that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with everyone else that CSS would be better. However, if you insist on doing it in Javascript, you can do as follows, inside your if block:

```
node.value = node.value.toString().toUpperCase();
```

Still, this is a way more intensive way of handling it than just using CSS.

Answer (score 4):

css:

```
input{text-transform:uppercase;}
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion but I'm trying to do it in JS if I can, but still going to use this as last resort

Comment: Why js? You should never use js for something css can do better.

Comment: why? Is it slower or has some kind of disadvatage?

Comment: It would require more code meaning it would take longer to download and calling a function on keypress (if that's what you were doing) would require more of the cpu.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `JS` for this just use `css`,

```
input {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: is there a way to do it in JS

Comment: definitely that why can't I tag your name?

Comment: All I can say is why?

Comment: but i need this as it only affects `input type="text"` areas in my code there are `input type="email"` areas too, when I modify your fiddle code this also affects them

Comment: So specify that in your css! `input[type="text"]{text-transform: uppercase;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You shuold set its text transform to Uppercase:

```
input
{
text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

For details go [**HERE**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp)

Comment: thanks for suggestion but as I commented in the other answers I'm trying to do it in jQuery/JS is there a way to do it?

Comment: @BrokenFrog js will  take more processing time , CSS is lightweight way